# Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token):

Tags: ros-melodic, xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Launch file

```
<launch>
        <arg name="model" />
        <command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg)/urdf/seven_dof_arm.xacro" param name="robot_description" />
        <param name="use_gui" value="true" />
        <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" />
        <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher" />
        <node name="rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg)/urdf.rviz" required="true" />
</launch>
```

I don't know what's wrong. Every time that I try run appear the same error:
RLException: Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token): line 3, column 9
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file

I checked the line, but there is nothing wrong.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323389/invalid-roslaunch-xml-syntax:-not-well-formed-(invalid-token):/) by [Jose-Araujo](https://answers.ros.org/users/40005/jose-araujo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-05-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Like the error says, you have invalid syntax in your launch file. The line

```
<command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg)/urdf/seven_dof_arm.xacro" param name="robot_description" />
```

Should probably be

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg)/urdf/seven_dof_arm.xacro" />
```

I found it on [the Qbotics Labs GitHub repo](https://github.com/qboticslabs/mastering_ros/blob/d83e78f30acc45b0f18522c1d5fae3a7f52974b9/chapter_2_codes/mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg/launch/view_arm.launch#L4).

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-05-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose-Araujo](https://answers.ros.org/users/40005/jose-araujo/) on 2019-05-16**:
So, when I use:

```
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg)/urdf/seven_dof_arm.xacro" />
```

Appear this erro:

```
RLException: Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [/home/jose/catkin_ws/src/xacro/xacro.py /home/jose/catkin_ws/src/mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg/urdf/seven_dof_arm.xacro] returned with code [2]. 
    
Param xml is <param command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg)/urdf/seven_dof_arm.xacro" name="robot_description"/>
    The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

And when I use:

```
<command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py $(find mastering_ros_robot_description_pkg)/urdf/seven_dof_arm.xacro" param name="robot_description" />
```

Appear this:

```
RLException: Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: not well-formed (invalid token): line 3, column 9.
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

**Comment by [kump](https://answers.ros.org/users/37695/kump/) on 2019-05-17**:
@Jose-Araujo The format @jayess suggested is definitely right. You are setting a parameter called `robot_description` to a rosparam server by processing the `seven_dof_arm.xacro` file. This file needs to have this xacro header

```
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="<your_robot>">
```

and needs to result in valid URDF file. That is if you use

```
rosrun xacro xacro path/to/seven_dof_arm.xacro > model.urdf
```

to convert the xacro file into URDF, and then

```
check_urdf model.urdf
```

to check validity of the URDF file.

It needs to say all is well formatted and print the structure tree into the terminal. So try those commands and see what it tells us.

**Comment by [Jose-Araujo](https://answers.ros.org/users/40005/jose-araujo/) on 2019-05-17**:
It's running now.
I find an error on xacro and changed what @kump and @jayess said.
Thank you!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-05-17**:
@Jose-Araujo That's great. Could you please click on the check mark (✓) to the left of the question to mark it as correct?